# Process Awaiting Command but sleep

Tags: sql-server

I am using a SQL Server database with Nodejs. I am using connection pool to perform various queries. When I run `sp_who2`, I can see that the there are almost 20 processes which have status `sleeping` and command awaiting command.

Should I go ahead and delete these processes? I read in some other post that this happens when you create a transaction in SQL Server but do not close / commit / rollback that transaction. I do not see any point in my application where I did not commit or rollback transaction on error. So I am not sure where the error came from.

I have a feeling that leaving those processes there is going to cause query timeout issues in the future. Is there a way to see what query caused the sleeping but waiting state?

Comment: you need show your code

Comment: Your process is blocked by some other process which has presumably having a table lock on some table which is used in your code. Identify the other process and kill it and your code will run.

Comment: Are you having an issue? Is the connection number steadily growing?  Are locks held?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally see many sleeping connections. I consider it normal. If you have sleeping connections with open transactions and locks, then you need to investigate. I would try to identify the host and PID holding the lock. In some cases the resolution is a polite talk with the person responsible for not closing their transaction.

A connection pool is a pool of connections to SQL Server. They will be idle and sleeping unless they are in use. Generally, there is a timeout for the connections in the pool. (For example, if you look at the ODBC control panel, the connection pooling tab will generally show a 60 second timeout. It might also always keep a minimum number of idle connections.) Check if you have a minimum number of idle connections. Once you know your timeout, verify that the connections are timing out as expected...eventually. If not, I would look for a connection leak or a connection pool issue. Is the application releasing the connection when done? Does GC have to run before the connection goes away?

Years ago there was an issue where a connection could go back into the pool with an open transaction. It was not until the connection was being prepared for reuse that it was finally reset. This issue has been fixed.

Another past issue was a broken connection. For example, if the SQL Server was rebooted, all idle connections are broken. However, it was not until the connection was requested that this was checked. A connection failure timeout was required for each connection in the pool before it was replaced. This was a PITA.